# Numpy where perform multiple actions

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have two dataframe columns where I want to check if the element of one are inside the other one. I perform this using the pandas `isin` method.
However, if the element is present in the second dataframe, I also want to subtract is from both:

`attivo['S'] = np.where(attivo['SKU'].isin(stampate['SKU-S']), attivo['S'] - 1, attivo['S'])`

In this example, if an item in the column `S` of  `attivo` dataframe is present in the column `SKU-S` of the `stampate` dataframe, the `S` column will decrease by one unit, however, I also want that the same column `S` will decrease in the `stampate` dataframe.

How is it possible to achieve this?

EDIT with sample data:

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({'SKU': 'productSKU', 'S': 5}, index=[0])`

`df2 = pd.DataFrame({'SKU-S': 'productSKU', 'S': 5}, index=[0])`

Currently, I am achieving this:

`df1['S'] = np.where(df1['SKU'].isin(df2['SKU-S']), df1['S'] - 1, df1['S'])`

[image]

However, I would like that both dataframes are updated, in this case, both of them will display 4 in the `S` column.

Comment: Do you mean whenever you find a `SKU` in `attivo`, then the `S` value of the same `SKU` in `stampate` decrease by `1`?

Comment: Not exactly, I mean exactly the `S` column with the `SKU-S` column. Since I have then different columns representing sizes I will adapt this code for multiple sizes.

Comment: You really should include a sample data and expected output.

Comment: You are correct, just edited. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = df1['SKU'].isin(df2['SKU-S'])

# modify df1
df1['S'] -= s

# count the SKU in df1 that belongs to df2 by values
counts = df1['SKU'].where(s).value_counts()

# modify df2
df2['S'] -= df2['SKU-S'].map(counts).fillna(0)
```

Comment: Exactly this. I didn't know that smart move to use the `-=` expression with a boolean! Thanks!